# How to exclude specific routes in routes.yaml

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony4

*There are similar questions on this subject but they talk about adding regex requirements for specific slugs within the route, which is not what I'm asking.*

Client side I'm using react and I want react to handle routing that doesn't include the term `api` in the route.

What I currently have

```
#App
app_dashboard:
    path:         /
    controller:   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController
    defaults:
        template: static/base.html.twig
    methods: GET
```

And this is what I've tried:

```
#App
app_dashboard:
    path:         /^(?!api).*
    controller:   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController
    defaults:
        template: static/base.html.twig
    methods: GET
```

and

```
#App
app_dashboard:
    path:         /
    controller:   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController
    condition: "context.getPathInfo() matches '/(?!api).*'"
    defaults:
        template: static/base.html.twig
    methods: GET
```

Each of the above throw the following error

> No route found

How do I apply regex to routes to exclude certain paths without using slugs?

Comment: so ... you want a specific controller to handle the api routes? my advice is to just define the api routes BEFORE the "catchall" route. symfony just uses the first route that matches, so define the api routes first and you should be golden.

Comment: @Jakumi thanks for the feedback. Could you advise on how to define this "catchall" route? :)

Comment: I was under the impression, that your react page route matched too many routes (i.e. the api stuff) and thus was supposed to be limited. limitation happens naturally, if other routes (that are positioned above that route) match first. so just add those routes above. I might have been mistaken regarding your intentions though

Comment: however, a catch-all route is also possible. the path would be just `/{slug}` and the requirements for that slug would be extended to `(.*)`. however, the same restriction as mentioned before applies. that route will "steal" the requests from routes defined later (because it always matches first).

Comment: Additional to Jakumi said, you can use `/{slug}`,  `/{slug1}/{slug2}`,  `/{slug1}/{slug2}/{slug3}` ... etc. to catch everything routes.